# Converting string to xml nodes

Tags: c#, php, xml, xmldocument

i have the string, it contains xml nodes, returned from the PHP file.
It's like

```
<a>1</a><b>0</b><c>4</c>..............
```

Now i need to find out what value each node have i.e a, b, c......
while loading this string to xmlDocument i'm getting error like "There are multiple root elements".

any solution for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the basic rules for [well-formed XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) that it has a single root node. With your example, you have multiple roots:

```
<a>1</a>
<b>0</b>
<c>4</c>
```

To make it well-formed you will have to make these elements a child of a single root:

```
<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>0</b>
    <c>4</c>
</root>
```

An XML document that is not well-formed is not really an XML document at all and you will find that no XML parser will be able to read it!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a root element. E.g:

From `<a>1</a><b>2</b>...`

To `<root><a>1</a><b>2</b>...</root>`

Then compute as normal.

Answer (score 2):

That is because each element is at the same level. There need to be a "root" that encloses all of them. Wrap them in a arbitrary node, say `<root>...</root>` then load the new string to the xmlDocument.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like XML, but it's not valid XML. In XML, you have a root element that wraps all of the other elements.

So, if you have that string in `str`, do this:

```
str = String.Format("<root>{0}</root>", str);
```